# How to ignore shortcode on html text search

Tags: html, wordpress, search, drop-down-menu, shortcode

I'm looking for a solution to a specific problem:

I am trying to use a w3schools dropdown menu with a search option with a combination of a shortcode for countries flags and I need that the search function will ignore the shortcode and just look for the countries name.
can someone please offer a solution?

Thanks from advance.

I am attaching the link to the basic w3schools html code and some screenshots for a better explanation:

[image]

[image]

My code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress Shortcodes are parsed at at runtime, so you actually need to worry about what the **output** of those shortcodes is. Likely something like `<img src="/path/to/flags/flag-1.png" />`

Since you clearly have control over the HTML markup inside the dropdown, I would just wrap the Country in a span, and target that with the JavaScript instead. Take the following snippet for example:

You'll note that it no longer cares about anything else inside the anchor, and instead only cares about the text inside the anchor's `span`.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        var label = a[i].querySelector('span');
        if (label.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn{background-color:#4CAF50;color:#fff;padding:16px;font-size:16px;border:none;cursor:pointer}.dropbtn:focus,.dropbtn:hover{background-color:#3e8e41}#myInput{border-box:box-sizing;background-image:url(searchicon.png);background-position:14px 12px;background-repeat:no-repeat;font-size:16px;padding:14px 20px 12px 45px;border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd}#myInput:focus{outline:#ddd solid 3px}.dropdown{position:relative;display:inline-block}.dropdown-content{display:none;position:absolute;background-color:#f6f6f6;min-width:230px;overflow:auto;border:1px solid #ddd;z-index:1}.dropdown-content a{color:#000;padding:12px 16px;text-decoration:none;display:block}.dropdown a:hover{background-color:#ddd}.show{display:block}
```

```html
<h2>Search/Filter Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu, and use the input field to search for a specific dropdown link.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about"><i class="flag a"></i><span>About</span></a>
    <a href="#base"><i class="flag b"></i><span>Base</span></a>
    <a href="#blog"><i class="flag b"></i><span>Blog</span></a>
    <a href="#contact"><i class="flag c"></i><span>Contact</span></a>
    <a href="#custom"><i class="flag c"></i><span>Custom</span></a>
    <a href="#support"><i class="flag s"></i><span>Support</span></a>
    <a href="#tools"><i class="flag t"></i><span>Tools</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, Xhynk!!! Great solution and working. thanks a lot. Just a small fix - for some reason the shortcode didn't executed in the <i class="[flag=il]"> so I put the flag outside like this: <a href="#Israel">[flag=il] <i class=""></i><span>Israel</span></a>. Thanks a lot man you saved me :)

Comment: You shouldn't actually need the `<i class="">` code at all, that was just supposed to illustrate the output from the shortcode. You should just need `<a href="…">[flag="il"]<span>Israel</span></a>` and it should work just fine!

Comment: Just erased the <i class=""> and it works fine. Thanks :)